# ansible - list of dictionaris to dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to take a list of dict link the following:

```
family:
- {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid1'}
- {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid2'}
- {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid3'}
- {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid4'}
```

and turn it into a dict of list:

```
{
  'lior':['kid1', 'kid2']
  'lew':['kid3', 'kid4']
}
```

I need it as a `set_fact` command in an ansible playbook. so far I was able to create it, but with one kid only (the last one)

```
- set_fact:
    names: "{{ names | default({}) | combine({ item.name: [item.kidname] }) }}"
    with_items: "{{ family }}"
```

basically my problem is the add an empty list and append to it, like I did for the key.

Thank you,
Lior

Answer (score 1):

I edited your initial attempt to append to the list

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    family:
      - {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid1'}
      - {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid2'}
      - {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid3'}
      - {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid4'}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        names: "{{ names | default({}) | combine({ item.name: names[item.name] | default([]) + [item.kidname] }) }}"
      with_items: "{{ family }}"

    - debug:
        var: names
```

Which outputs

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "names": {
        "lew": [
            "kid3",
            "kid4"
        ],
        "lior": [
            "kid1",
            "kid2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter [*groupby*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        names: "{{ dict(_names|zip(_kids)) }}"
      vars:
        _families: "{{ family|groupby('name') }}"
        _names: "{{ _families|map('first')|list }}"
        _kids: "{{ _families|map('last')|map('map', attribute='kidname')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  names:
    lew:
    - kid3
    - kid4
    lior:
    - kid1
    - kid2
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a custom filter:

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py** and the filter **DictList**)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {

            'DictList': self.DictList
        }

    def DictList(self, obj, ky, vl):
        dict = {}
        for d in obj:
            key = d[ky]
            if key in dict:
                dict[key].append(d[vl])
            else:
                dict[key] = [d[vl]]
        return dict
```

i have built generic filter where you notify the key and value:

use:

```
- name: vartest
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    family:
    - {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid1'}
    - {'name': 'lior', 'kidname': 'kid2'}
    - {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid3'}
    - {'name': 'lew', 'kidname': 'kid4'}  

  tasks:
    - name: display password
      set_fact:
        dictlist: "{{ family| DictList( 'name', 'kidname') }}" 

    - name: display result
      debug:
        msg: "{{dictlist}}"
```

---

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "lew": [
            "kid3",
            "kid4"
        ],
        "lior": [
            "kid1",
            "kid2"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
from collections import defaultdict

names = defaultdict(list)

for d in family:
    names[d['name']].append(d['kidname'])
```

output:

```
>>> names
defaultdict(list, {'lior': ['kid1', 'kid2'], 'lew': ['kid3', 'kid4']})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an ansible code. Python won't save me this time